# Struggling to make a program that has variables that change when a button is pressed on Python

Tags: python, tkinter

You start with 10,000 money. Buying costs 100 and selling will give you 70.

This is what I have so far:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def Buy():
  print("Stock bought")
  global money
  money = 10000

def Sell():
  print("sold")
  global money 
  money = money 
  
  
  

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

Buy = tk.Button(frame, text="Buy(Cost 100)", fg="red" ,command=Buy :money-100 )
Buy.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

Sell = tk.Button(frame,text="Sell",command=Sell :money+70 )
Sell.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

I can't seem to change the variable money, I ran the code and it does this

*Click buy stocks*
bought
9900
*Click sell*
sold
10070

It doesnt change it to 9970 instead it changes to 10070, can someone please tell me what's wrong with my code and how to can fix it.

Comment: What version of python is this that supports the `:money-100` syntax? v3.6 doesn't for me

Comment: @TankorSmash I use the repl.it online ide and I'm pretty sure it runs the latest version of python

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. You should create your own Answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own Answer). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are resetting `money` to 10,000 when clicking on function `Buy`. Hence, after clicking sell, you are summing 70 to 10,000. This is the problem. To solve it, initialize the variable `money` at the beginning and delete `money=10000` from `Buy` function:

```
import tkinter as tk

money = 10000

def Buy():
  print("Stock bought")
  global money
```

As @TankorSmash has mentioned, I cannot make it work because of `:money-100` (I am running Python v3.5.2). Anyway, the following code makes it work:

```
import tkinter as tk

money = 10000

def Buy():
  print("Stock bought")
  global money
  money -= 100
  print(money)

def Sell():
  print("sold")
  global money 
  money += 70 
  print(money)

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

Buy = tk.Button(frame, text="Buy(Cost 100)", fg="red" ,command=Buy)
Buy.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

Sell = tk.Button(frame,text="Sell",command=Sell)
Sell.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Print:

```
Stock bought
9900
sold
9970
```